# How can render a reactJs in a nested Object Array?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

How can get tchStudents inside the array and render it in reactJS?
[image]

```
 const {
      tchFirstName, 
      tchLastName, 
      tchStudents
 } = teacher; 

 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{tchID}</td>
      <td>{tchFirstName}</td>
      <td>{tchLastName}</td>
      <td>{tchStudents.stdID} // ←←← this is Schema.Types.ObjectId 
    </td>

 Object.keys(tchStudents).map((key) => (tchStudents[key].map((item) =>
    <p> {item.stdID} </p> 
    )
 ))
```

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, stdStatus, stdID, stdFirstName, stdLastName, stdGender, __v}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Thank you for helping me out!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
data.docs.map(x => x.tchStudentsCopy)
```

Then if you want to use whatever is inside the tchStudentsCopy array, do another map to extract what you want.

Comment: wait amila Im edit first